# Resetear valores de un Bean de Sesion en JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Buenas tardes, quería saber si por favor alguien me podría ayudar con lo siguiente , ya que busco y no encuentro una solución.

Tengo un formulario llamado "formuPrestamo" , el cual recoge valores de un managedBean de tipo Session llamado "frances" en un inputText (que al principio tiene todo 0) realiza algunas operaciones y redirecciona a otra pagina.

El problema esta en que cuando vuelvo a abrir el formulario "formuPrestamo" los valores del managedBean siguen en los inputText y necesito que esos valores esten en 0 nuevamente.

Desde ya muchas Gracias.

Saludos.

vista

```
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:fieldset>


                    <p:fieldset legend="Datos de Préstamo" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                        <p:ajax event="toggle"  listener="#{vistaFieldSet.handleToggle(event)}" update="msgs"/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                            <p:outputLabel value="Monto Prestado:" for="montoprestado" />
                            <p:inputText id="montoprestado"  value="#{frances.montoSolicitado}" title="Montoprestado" 
                                         readonly="true" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de Solicitud:" for="fechaSolicitud" />
                            <p:inputText id="fechaSolicitud"  value="#{frances.fechaSolicitud}" title="FechaSolicitud" 
                                         readonly="true"
                                         >
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Cuotas:" for="cantidadCuotas" />
                            <p:inputText id="cantidadCuotas" value="#{frances.plazo}" title="CantidadCuotas" 
                                         readonly="true"
                                         />
                            <p:outputLabel value="TNA %:" for="tna" />
                            <p:inputText id="tna" value="#{frances.tasa}" title="Tna"
                                         readonly="true"/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Gastos Adm:" for="gastosAdm" />
                            <p:inputText id="gastosAdm" value="#{frances.go}"  title="GastosAdm"
                                         readonly="true"/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Seg. de Vida:" for="seguroVida" />
                            <p:inputText id="seguroVida" value="#{frances.sv}"  title="SeguroVida"/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="IVA %:" for="iva" />
                            <p:inputText id="iva" value="#{frances.iv}"  title="IVA" 
                                         readonly="true"/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Observación:" for="observacion" />
                            <p:inputTextarea id="observacion" value="#{prestamoController.prestamo.observacion}" title="Observacion" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="somDoc" value="Estado "/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="somDoc" value="#{prestamoController.estadoPrestamo.idestadoprestamo}" 
                                             converter="javax.faces.Integer"
                                             required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar el estado del préstamo">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue=""/>
                                <!--<f:selectItem itemLabel="Activo" itemValue="1"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cancelado" itemValue="2"/>-->
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pendiente de Pago" itemValue="3"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>


                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:fieldset>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnBoton" 
                                     icon="ui-icon-check" value="#{app['boton.grant']}" 
                                     action="#{prestamoController.otorgarPrestamo()}"
                                     update="msgs"
                                     ajax="false"/>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnBotn" 
                                     icon="ui-icon-print" value="#{app['boton.print']}"  
                                     action="#{prestamoController.exportarPDF()}"
                                     ajax="false"/>

                </h:form>
```

Método otorgar préstamo

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
        JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(rf.getMensajeArb("info.save"));
        //remover:
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("Frances");

        return "/faces/pages/prestamo/simulaPrestamo.xhtml?faces­redirect=true";
```

Comment: Revisa si tiene sentido ese scope, si no te interesa mantener los datos durante toda la sesión quiza sea el scope incorrecto. Por que no al otorgar el préstamo seteas en null todos los atributos de tu bean?

Comment: Puedes agregar un <f:event type="preRenderView" ... />  que limpie el o los objetos que usas en esa vista.

Comment: @Voiser y mmartinez, son dos buenas opciones, deberíais convertirlas en respuestas.

Comment: Uso ese scope porque necesito ir cambiando de vistas y mantener los valores , con request y con view los pierdo...  vi que también podía mantenerlos con wizard de primefaces o flash Scope pero estoy a contrareloj y ya no puedo cambiar...

Probé la opción propuesta por @mmartinez7 y funcionó.
De todos modos también probare la opción de voiser.

Muchísimas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: @SJuan76 lo agregué como respuesta explayandome un poco más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero  si es necesario que tu MB tenga un scope Sesion  tendrás que limpiar sus valores una vez ya no sean usados, en tu caso si se regresa a esa vista y los valores no se resetearon, evidentemente al ser un bean de  sesión  estos se mantienen vivos.

Para ello puedes hacer uso  preRenderView, que lo que hará es:
 Antes de renderizar la vista ejecutará el alguna validación o en tu caso limpiar los objetos y propiedades  que tu indiques.[facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html)

Un ejemplo mínimo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >

    <f:event listener="#{bean.limpiar}" type="preRenderView" />

    <h:body>

        <h1>Todos los componentes se limpiaran antes de hacer render</h1>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

En el MB agregas el metodo que sera invocado, dentro de este pon todo lo que deseas limpiar al momento que se  pinte la vista.

```
import javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean{

  public void limpiar(ComponentSystemEvent event){

    //Antes de  hacer  render se llama a este metodo
    //Limpiara los objetos o propiedades
    texto1 = "";
    cantidad1 = 0;
    obj = null

  }
}
```

Si puedes cambiar el scope de tu bea, puedes hacerlo viewScope  o request, siendo así puedes agregar un metodo anotado con @PostConstrut

```
@PostConstruct
   public void limpiar() {
       texto1 = "";
        cantidad1 = 0;
        obj = new Object();

   }
```

Da una vuelta en los siguientes enlaces :

[preRender View / view Action Vs PostConstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)

El código de  la respuesta no lo testie, pero debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias voiser tu respuesta me fue muy util , funcionó perfecto. Saludos

Comment: @franciscocastillo aparte de informar de que la respuesta ha sido correcta, deberías marcarla como aceptada (hay una marca de aceptar junto a la cabecera de cada respuesta) para que Voiser tenga los puntos, la gente que busque preguntas parecidas pueda ver fácilmente que ésta está bien respondida, la estadísticas del sitio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Que versión de JSF estas utilizando?

Con la versión 2.0 se agregó `@ConversationScoped()`, el cual permite definir un inicio y un fín del ciclo de vida de tu `managedBean`. Este scope ya existía en frameworks [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html) como [SeamFramework](http://seamframework.org/) y luego pasó a ser parte del estándar de JSF 2.0

El Conversation scope se adecúa mejor a tu problema, ya que mantener información a través de varios `redirect` no implica necesariamente que sea a lo largo de toda la sesión.

Ejemplo:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named()
@ConversationScoped()
public class ManagedBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String value;
    private Integer otherValue;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    public String onSomeClick() {
         conversation.begin();
        return "nextpage?faces-redirect=true";
    }

 public String onFinish() {
    conversation.end();
    cleanData();
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}

private void cleanData(){
 value = null;
 otherValue = null;

}

// getters and setters ...
```